# Strange behavior of the progressbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

To download a JSON file from an NVD site I use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import requests
import re
chunk_size = 1024
# Download JSON
year = input("Enter year: ")
url = requests.get('https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED')
for filename in re.findall("nvdcve-1.1-" + year + "\.json\.zip", url.text):
    print("\r[!] Received file: " + filename)
    r = requests.get("https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/" + filename, stream=True)
    total_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
    with open("/tmp/" + filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in tqdm(iterable=r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size), total=total_size / chunk_size, unit='KB'):
            f.write(chunk)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n[+] The download is complete")
```

When running this application, everything works well and the file is downloaded, but a strange error appears in Pycham and the terminal:

```
82%|████████▏ | 2726/3342.5546875 [00:00<00:00, 1478.94KB/s]/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py:522: TqdmWarning: clamping frac to range [0, 1]
full_bar = Bar(
100%|██████████| 3343/3342.5546875 [00:00<00:00, 3577.67KB/s]
[+] The download is complete
```

Tell me, please, what is the problem?
I searched all over google, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: It looks like the lib is not redirecting it's output to the stderr https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/681

Comment: @AlexanderJardim, many thanks for the link, I found a material that seemed to help me.
I added one parameter `dynamic_ncols=True` and everything seems to work as it should. I'm still testing in different situations and operating systems.
Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to write an answer to your question, so future user can benefit from this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a tip on the resource [github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/681](http://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/681) further [github.com/tqdm/tqdm#redirecting-writing](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#redirecting-writing) there i found that you can set the parameter: `dynamic_ncols=True`
as a result, it turned out like this:

```
for chunk in tqdm(iterable=r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size), total=total_size / chunk_size, unit=' KB', dynamic_ncols=True):
```

now everything works and no error \ warning appears. Checked on several operating systems.